# Repetitive javascript call. can not disable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use a JavaScript function to change the page when a function is clicked. An ajax call is made inside the function.
As the browser is slow. If I click more than one time on the button before the page changes (AJax div load. Page actually not changed), an ajax call is made for each click.
I used the following method to prevent. But even it is called many times. How can I prevent it?

```
var isClicked = function() {}
isClicked.init = function() {
    this.clicked = false;
}

function myAjaxFunction {
    //some statements
    if(isClicked.clicked == 'undefined')
        isClicked.clicked = false;

    if(isClicked.clicked)
        return false;

    isClicked.clicked = true;
     // my ajax call here
    isClicked.clicked = false;
    //some statements
}
```

Comment: Are you setting `isClicked.clicked` back to `false` in your Ajax success callback (the `onreadystatechange` handler)? In your abbreviated code it looks like you set it immediately, _before_ the asynchronous Ajax call has completed (though it's hard to tell when you don't show the code). Also, why not just `var isClicked = false;` and then `if(isClicked) return false`? You don't need to declare it as a function and set properties on the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var isClicked = false;  

function AjaxFunction(){

    if(isClicked){
        return false;
    }

    // Set your variable.
    isClicked = true;

    // Do yourAjaxCall and use isClicked = false in the callback of that function.

}
```